# Error on stackexchange.com - "Server Error in '/' Application"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, 500-server-error

When you go in [stackexchange](https://stackexchange.com/) you get [this page](https://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/):

[image: Fail Pic]

I'm not sure where to post this but here seems like the right place...

Reproduced here using Firefox and Chrome.
What info is needed for repro?

Comment: norepro. The SE homepage loads for me just fine.

Comment: ... and your link leads to an upside-down panda

Comment: Still happens here. Tried chrome and firefox.

Comment: It been happening to me all (UK) morning. I suspect it's a single server that's affected so it won't be happening to everyone and it may well not happen all the time.

Comment: Reproduced here as well, (Toronto, Canada)

Comment: Should work fine now, can you confirm?

Comment: @balpha - works for me OK now.

Comment: @balpha working fine for me, same place as OP and same browser. What did you do?

Comment: @balpha - Yes. Works okay. That was quick!

Comment: Works for me now too

Comment: I was having the same problem yesterday, but now it seems to be fixed for me also.

Comment: Sweet, my screenshot made it in without me knowing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

stackexchange.com is behaving very strangely today on two of our webservers. Luckily we have nine of them available, so until we've found and fixed the underlying issue I've taken those two servers out of the load balancer, letting the remaining (apparently not drunk) web servers handle the traffic.

Comment: Any chance it's related to the anti DoS system you're testing?

Comment: So I was wrong. It wasn't a single server ;)