# StackExchange site broken again

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com

The StackExchange site is broken again.  The symptoms are identical to previous failures like those reported in [Error on stackexchange.com - "Server Error in '/' Application"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243031/error-on-stackexchange-com-server-error-in-application) .

Here is the error that the site presents when visiting it (via a redirect to `stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/`):

> **Server Error in '/' Application.**
>   Runtime Error
>   Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

If only there was a site that StackExchange could use to find some programmers... just kidding.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Going to the site root, I get the hot network page.

Comment: @Oded I don't.  Tried 8 times.

Comment: no repro for me in EDGE, Chrome, FF on Win 10. I'm on a route from Western Europe, probably passing AMS-IX.

Comment: OK here. @Oded Could it be that only one of the servers is down?

Comment: OK - one of the webservers was throwing OOM exceptions for the se.com app pool, it has been restarted. // cc @ChrisF

Comment: Just tried again.  Now it's working.

Comment: @Oded I noticed you removed the **bug** tag.  Given that there are reports of this occurring before as well, is this a bug?

Comment: @Oded how exactly it's not a bug? If can't reproduce, there's a [tag:status-norepro] for this...

Answer (score 8):

We had a misbehaving app pool on one of the servers - evidently, one that you kept hitting.

We restarted the app pool and all is well in the se.com world.

Thanks for reporting!

Comment: You're welcome!  Thanks for rebooting!

Comment: Wasn't me - I just told our chief rebooter ;)

Comment: How do I apply for *that* job?   :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here

Comment: Thanks.  Let me know if you ever create a position of *Chief Rebooter*.  You can either hire me or my cat that likes to pull out power cords.